# three.js - Trying to include a subwindow into main window

Tags: javascript, three.js, zooming

I try to include, into a main window (representing sphere), a subwindow representing a zoomed view of this sphere.

For this moment, I can display a right-bottom subwindow containing the three axes of main scene. These axes are rotating the same way I make rotate the sphere with mouse.

Now, I would like to display, into this subwindow, a zoomed view of the sphere instead of having the subwindow with 3D axes.

From [Can multiple WebGLRenderers render the same scene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612524/can-multiple-webglrenderers-render-the-same-scene), we can't use a second time the `THREE.WebGLRenderer()` for the subwindow.

From [How to render the same scene with different cameras in three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173893/how-to-render-the-same-scene-with-different-cameras-in-three-js) ,a solution may be to use `setViewport` function but I don't know if I can display the zoom of sphere in this subwindow.

I tried to do in `render()` function :

```
function render() {
    controls.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    zoomCamera.position.copy(camera.position);
    zoomCamera.position.sub(controls.target);
    zoomCamera.position.setLength(500);
    zoomCamera.lookAt(zoomScene.position );

    // Add Viewport for zoomScene
    renderer.setViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    zoomRenderer.setViewport(0, 0, 200 , 200);
    zoomRenderer.render(zoomScene, zoomCamera);

  }
```

From your advices, is it possible technically to have 2 object in the same time (one on main window and the other on right-bottom subwindow) ?

Can I solve my issue with `setViewport` ?

And if someone could give documentation on `setViewport`, this would be great.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE :**

@WestLangley , thanks, I did your modifications (with a unique scene) but the content of inset does not appear.

I think that issue comes from the fact that I don't know how to make the link between `the container of inset` and the drawing of this `inset`.

For example, into the link above, I tried :

```
...
 // Add sphere to main scene
  scene.add(sphere);

  camera.position.z = 10;

  var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);

  // If I include these two lines below, nothing appears 
  // zoomContainer = document.getElementById('zoomContainer');
  // zoomContainer.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // Zoom camera
  zoomCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, zoomWidth, zoomHeight, 1, 1000);
  zoomCamera.position.z = 20;
  zoomCamera.up = camera.up; // important!

  // Call rendering function
  render();

  function render() {

  controls.update();
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  zoomCamera.position.copy(camera.position);
  zoomCamera.position.sub(controls.target); 
  zoomCamera.position.setLength(camDistance);
  zoomCamera.lookAt(scene.position);

  // Add zoomCamera to main scene
  scene.add(zoomCamera);

  // render scene
  renderer.clear();
  renderer.setViewport(0, 0, width, height);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  // render inset
  renderer.clearDepth(); // important!
  renderer.setViewport(10, height - zoomHeight - 10, zoomWidth, zoomHeight);
  renderer.render(scene, zoomCamera);
```

}

Given that I have only one renderer, I don't knwo how to assign the `"inset" container` to the renderer of `Viewport` (i.e with the good `renderer.setViewport`)

Would you have got a workaround ?

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. Rather than asking if something is possible, it is better to try first, and then ask a question.

Comment: @WestLangley I did your modifications and you can see above an update of my issue. Unfortunately, the content of inset is not displayed. I didn't forget to put "renderer.autoClear = false;" . It seems this is an error about the inset container.

Comment: (1) If you use the first camera for the inset, the sphere appears in the upper left of your canvas. So you have a bug. (2) A viewport is not a div. It is a sub-region of the canvas. Work on it for 24 hours. I expect you can get it working.

Comment: @WestLangley thanks a lot, that works ! issue was wrong parameters into PerspectiveCamera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to render another view of your scene in an inset window.

Create one scene, and two cameras.

Make sure you set `autoClear` to `false` when you instantiate the renderer.

```
renderer.autoClear = false;
```

Then, in your render loop, use this pattern

```
// render scene
renderer.clear();
renderer.setViewport( 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.render( scene, camera );

// render inset
renderer.clearDepth(); // important!
renderer.setViewport( 10, window.innerHeight - insetHeight - 10, insetWidth, insetHeight );
renderer.render( scene, camera2 );
```

three.js r.75