# Three.js scene within hud

Tags: javascript, three.js, hud

I would like to create a Three.js scene within a hud which is already in a Three.js scene. So essentially I would like to create a Three.js scene within a scene.

To elaborate a bit further see the link  [here](http://www.ladybug.tools/spider/sandbox/scatter-well/get-google-spreadsheet-data/get-google-spreadsheet-data-r2.html)

If you hold your mouse over one of the shapes in the scene you will see that a hud pops up. How can I get a three.js scene appearing in each hud when it pops up?

The code to create the hud can be seen here:
https://github.com/ladybug-tools/spider/blob/master/sandbox/scatter-well/r1/index-00.html#L313-L345 (as well as the code for the whole scene)

Code samples and pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028810/three-js-trying-to-include-a-subwindow-into-main-window

Comment: This might be interesting for a window within a window example : https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_multiple_elements

Comment: Are the two scenes the same/related, or do they have different shapes in them?